# MySQL Join two tables and combine multiple rows into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

**sms_recipients**

```
campaign_id | message | user_id | contact_number | status
.........................................................
1            something  12334     078237812719     1
1            something  12123     071231231232     1
2            other      12124     078123123126     0
2            other      12334     078234234212     0
2            other      42124     078124124415     1
```

**sms_campaign**

```
campaign_id | shop_id| campaign_type
.....................................
1             1123     marketing
2             2123     awareness
3             3231     something else
4             4432     bla bla
5             5244     last
```

`campaign_id`'s are unique for the `sms_campaign` table, there are multiple `user_id`'s related to the same `campaign_id` the `message` is the same for all  unique `champagne_id`

I want to combine them so that every `contact_number`  of the same `campaign_id` with a `status = 0` appears in a single row and column like this:

```
campaign_id | shop_id| campaign_type | users_mobile_numbers      | message
..........................................................................
1             1123     marketing                                  something 
2             2123     awareness       078123123126,078234234212  other      
3             3231     something else
4             4432     078234234212
5             5244     078124124415
```

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT c.campaign_id, 
shop_id,
campaign_type, 
contact_number AS users_mobile_numbers, 
message FROM sms_campaign c 
LEFT JOIN sms_recipients r 
ON u.campaign_id = c.campaign_id 
WHERE status = 0
```

Comment: Use GROUP_CONCAT function.
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Comment: You have multiple shop_ids and messages per campaign?- how should we resolve which one to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `LEFT JOIN`, you will need to either move the filter `status = 0` into a join condition, OR if you leave the filter in the WHERE clause, then `status = 0 OR status IS NULL` to avoid filtering out campaigns with no messages at all - I've done the first option.

As per the comment, you will need to `GROUP` the data by the campaign columns, and apply aggregate functions to all non-grouped columns, in order to guarantee just one row per group - `GROUP_CONCAT` will concatenate all text values in each GROUP. I've arbitrarily used `MIN` to resolve a value for `shop` and `message`, but you may need to adjust otherwise. (You can also do a DISTINCT in a GROUP CONCAT, if required).

```
SELECT 
  c.campaign_id, 
  MIN(shop_id) AS shop_id,
  campaign_type, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(contact_number) AS users_mobile_numbers, 
  MIN(message) AS message
FROM sms_campaign c 
LEFT JOIN sms_recipients r 
  ON u.campaign_id = c.campaign_id AND status = 0
GROUP BY c.campaign_id, campaign_type;
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the condition on `r.status` to the `ON` clause of the outer join. (With the condition in the WHERE clause requiring `r.status` to be non-NULL, that will negate the outerness of the LEFT JOIN, making it equivalent to an INNER JOIN.)

Add a `GROUP BY` clause to collapse the rows.

Use a `GROUP_CONCAT` function to combine the values of `contact_number`. Column references which appear in the SELECT list but are not included in the GROUP BY clause should also be enclosed in aggregate expressions.)

```
SELECT c.campaign_id
     , ...

     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.contact_number ORDER BY r.contact_number) AS `c_numbers`

     , MIN(r.message) AS `message`

 FROM campaign c 
 LEFT
 JOIN sms_recipients r 
   ON r.campaign_id = c.campaign_id 
  AND r.status = 0
GROUP BY c.campaign_id
```

---

The value returned by `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate function is limited by `max_group_concat_len` variable. Longer values will be silently truncated to the maximum length.